# how to find out the address pool for DDOS Attack IP addresses

Tags: security

Of recent I have been experiencing DDOS attacks against my mail server with a series of IP addresses. I have been blocking these IP addresses one by one using the firewall. The process was and is still a pain, so I contacted the ISP responsible for these IP addresses and nothing has been done. Right now I need to find out the address pool to which they belong so that I can simply block the whole damn pool of addresses. Anybody has an idea how to do this?

Comment: Do you have any evidence showing you that the source IP addresses are authentic? If not, then it is possible that the source IP has been spoofed.

Comment: I listed them down and sent the list I had received so far to the ISP. When I run the who is on the IP addresses, they do point me to the ISP in question. If the IP addresses have been spoofed, then it their (ISP) job to fix the problem, because not only is it affecting me but themselves too

Comment: That makes no sense at all. If the source IP has been spoofed there is nothing they could do about it. The packets may have been nowhere near their network.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to set `iptables` to limit number of connection per host.
Ddos can use unlimited number of ip addresses

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 50/minute --limit-burst 200 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 50/second --limit-burst 50 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT
```

`-p tcp --dport 25` => Specifies traffic on port 25 (smtp).

`-m state NEW` => This rule applies to NEW connections.

`-m limit --limit 50/minute --limit-burst 200 -j ACCEPT` =>This is the essence of preventing DOS.

`--limit-burst` is a bit confusing, but in a nutshell 200 new connections (packets really) are allowed before the limit of 50 NEW connections (packets) per minute is applied.

Second rule – Limit established traffic
This rule applies to `RELATED` and `ESTABLISHED` all traffic on all ports
In summary, `50 ESTABLISHED` (and/or `RELATED`) connections (packets really) are allowed before the limit of `50 ESTABLISHED` (and/or `RELATED`) connections (packets) per second is applied.

or use set of rules for all input

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m limit --limit 50/minute --limit-burst 200 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT
```

Also you have answer from [Oli](https://askubuntu.com/users/449/oli) and usage of `whois`

Comment: This will help stop service-level DDoS (eg something using all the CPU because there's too much going on) but won't stop an attack bunging up your network. [That's much harder to stop](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/33819/12764).

Comment: @Oli, yes this would not completely wallop out the DDOS attack but at least it would keep it at the minimum or in check. Monitor connections and block whatever matches the suspicious rules.

Comment: Only ISPs on core equipment can really stop `DDOS`. If you have virtual server or server on your net range, witch belong  ISPs, you can not defent you self. DDos will be router to the last router in network aka last ISPs router, like usual traffic. When traffic evaluate to DDOS then ISP can discard them.  If is very large amount of traffic routed to you server, service will not be available for regular traffic.  ...

Comment: Sometimes `-j DROP` is more practical than REJECT.

Answer (score 2):

For an allocation block of IPs, you can just `whois` the IP you have. This will only get you as far as the ISP level usually unless you're talking about a company big enough to have its own allocations. For example, here's what I see if I enter the IP address of one of my servers:

```
$ whois 109.74.xxx.yyy
% This is the RIPE Database query service.
% The objects are in RPSL format.
%
% The RIPE Database is subject to Terms and Conditions.
% See http://www.ripe.net/db/support/db-terms-conditions.pdf

% Note: this output has been filtered.
%       To receive output for a database update, use the "-B" flag.

% Information related to '109.74.192.0 - 109.74.199.255'

...
```

The block there is `109.74.192.0 - 109.74.199.255`. You can use a [subnet calculator](https://www.dan.me.uk/ipsubnets) (or big brains) to work out that that's `109.74.192.0/21`, and just block that.

... But that's a *lot* of servers, and not just mine.

---

It seems unlikely that a DDoS would be coming from just one network though. The rest of this answer assumes that we're actually talking about something coming from many networks though parts of it may still apply to single-network ingress.

Unless you can get into a *command-and-control* situation over this botnet —which is extremely unlikely— you'll never know the full scope of it, you'll never know which IPs it contains other than the ones that connect to you.

This may well not be a denial of service attack, it might be:

- People trying to hack the MTA. Like any service, they occasionally contain flaws that can be tested. Mailservers are particularly talkative and poorly configured which makes them a good target. There's nothing you can do about this.
- Is it an open relay? Are spammers just relaying their email through your machine? If you are, stop running an open relay.

I generally recommend not running mailservers. People who do it professionally, as their only job tend to do it better: focussed security, bigger and more robust networks and much better spam detection that comes from scanning hundreds of billions of incoming emails a day. The cost is usually very justifiable.

Comment: Thanks Oli, I am not running an open relay. All these connections are those that are trying to connect but then fail and keep trying until I block them through the firewall. I think I still need to ponder the ISP responsible for them to do something about it. As you said, it is a large pool and blocking the whole pool may include other regitimate/innocent  IP addresses

Comment: A large network organization (ISP, mobile operator, hosting provider…) usually has *many* distinct IP blocks allocated to it.